# ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST") returns different response on different web servers

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

We are using ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST") to identify the workstation accessing a classic ASP page (internal company workstations, not scanning public users) as I cannot assume that an IP address will always apply to the same workstation.

I find that the REMOTE_HOST value returned to a Win7 IIS server includes the domain name after the host name, but a VM server 2008 instance of IIS does not include the domain name.

I would like to be able to program for a consistent value and not have to mess around trying to match values with/without a predefined domain name string on the end.

Does anybody know if this is determined by configuration on IIS or the server O/S?

Comment: As correctly stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3812239/447356), the REMOTE_HOST will return the IP address when the host name can't be resolved. You can just use `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR ")` to have it return consistent values.

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR is not useful as I cannot be certain that all workstations will always have the same address.  As my question outlines, I am getting host names, either with or without the domain appended to them, in different circumstances.